# Decoding Base64urlUInt-encoded value

Tags: c#, base64, rsa, openid-connect, jwk

What I am generally trying to do, is to validate an **id_token** value obtained from an OpenID Connect provider (e.g. Google). The token is signed with the RSA algorithm and the public key is read from the [Discovery](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#ProviderMetadata) document (the **jwks_uri** parameter). For example, Google keys are available [here](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs) in the JWK format:

```
{
  kty: "RSA",
  alg: "RS256",
  use: "sig",
  kid: "38d516cbe31d4345819b786d4d227e3075df02fc",
  n: "4fQxF6dFabDqsz9a9-XgVhDaadTBO4yBZkpUyUKrS98ZtpKIQRMLoph3bK9Cua828wwDZ9HHhUxOcbcUiNDUbubtsDz1AirWpCVRRauxRdRInejbGSqHMbg1bxWYfquKKQwF7WnrrSbgdInUZPv5xcHEjQ6q_Kbcsts1Nnc__8YRdmIGrtdTAcm1Ga8LfwroeyiF-2xn0mtWDnU7rblQI4qaXCwM8Zm-lUrpSUkO6E1RTJ1L0vRx8ieyLLOBzJNwxpIBNFolMK8-DYXDSX0SdR7gslInKCn8Ihd9mpI2QBuT-KFUi88t8TW4LsoWHAwlgXCRGP5cYB4r30NQ1wMiuQ",
  e: "AQAB"
}
```

I am going to use the [RSACryptoServiceProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) class for decoding the signature. To initialize it, I have to provide [RSAParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsaparameters(v=vs.110).aspx) with the Modulus and Exponent values. These values are read from the above JWK as **n** and **e** correspondingly. According to the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-6.3.1.1), these values are Base64urlUInt-encoded values:

> The representation of a positive or zero integer value as the
> base64url encoding of the value's unsigned big-endian representation
> as an octet sequence.  The octet sequence MUST utilize the minimum
> number of octets needed to represent the value.  Zero is represented
> as BASE64URL(single zero-valued octet), which is "AA".

So, my question is how to decode these values to put them to RSAParameters? I tried decoding them as a common Base64url string (`Convert.FromBase64String(modulusRaw)`), but this obviously does not work and generates this error:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64
> character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character
> among the padding characters.

Comment: Does `HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode` not work in your case?

Comment: @Baldrick Thanks! However, this does not work in this situation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[RFC 7515](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515.txt) defines base64url encoding like this:

> Base64 encoding using the URL- and filename-safe character set
>   defined in Section 5 of [RFC 4648](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc4648), with all trailing '='
>   characters omitted (as permitted by Section 3.2) and without the
>   inclusion of any line breaks, whitespace, or other additional
>   characters.  Note that the base64url encoding of the empty octet
>   sequence is the empty string.  (See Appendix C for notes on
>   implementing base64url encoding without padding.)

RFC 4648 defines "Base 64 Encoding with URL and Filename Safe Alphabet" as regular base64, but:

- The padding may be omitted (as it is here)
- Using `-` instead of `+` and `_` instead of `/`

So to use regular `Convert.FromBase64String`, you just need to reverse that process:

```
static byte[] FromBase64Url(string base64Url)
{
    string padded = base64Url.Length % 4 == 0
        ? base64Url : base64Url + "====".Substring(base64Url.Length % 4);
    string base64 = padded.Replace("_", "/")
                          .Replace("-", "+");
    return Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
}
```

It's possible that this code already exists somewhere in the framework, but I'm not aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

Who ever comes here from Java: there are two methods in `java.util.Base64`:

- `getDecoder()`
- `getUrlDecoder()`

As you probably assumed: taking the second one does all the chars replacements for you already.